# getResource returns boolean instead String[]

Tags: android, resources, android-resources, getresource

In an IntentService class i want to put some Arrays from Android xml files in an ArrayList, Android-Studio doesnt accept this, but only if i want to add it in an ArrayList. Android Studio says it found a Boolean instead a String[]. But why Boolean? this are String[]. In another Code-Fragment, i can work with this String[] that i get from getResources() without a problem.

```
private ArrayList<String[]> alleTermine = new ArrayList<String[]>();

private String[] hausmuell;
private String[] gelbeSaecke;
private String[] gruenAbfall;
private String[] altPapier;



public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Resources res = getResources();
     //this makes a String[]
    hausmuell = res.getStringArray(R.array.hausmuell);
    gelbeSaecke = res.getStringArray(R.array.gelber_sack);
    gruenAbfall = res.getStringArray(R.array.gruenabfall);
    altPapier = res.getStringArray(R.array.altpapier);
    alleTermine=alleTermine.add(hausmuell)
}
```

The xml.file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <resources>
 <string-array name='hausmuell'>
 <item>1482451200000</item>
  <item>1452214800000</item>
 <item>1453424400000</item>
 <item>1454634000000</item>
 <item>1455843600000</item>

 </string-array>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Add the array.xml file please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alleTermine=alleTermine.add(hausmuell)
```

[`ArrayList#add()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) method returns a boolean, and you're trying to assign the return value to an `ArrayList`. That won't compile.

You probably want something like:

```
alleTermine = new ArrayList<>();
alleTermine.add(hausmuell);
```

Comment: alleTermine = new ArrayList<>();

it's still the same,

Comment: android-studio says: "hausmuell" is the boolean, not "alleTermine".